# Discrepency of 600 years: Velikovsky's view on Jewish history

Tags: sources-mekorot, history, rambam, chronology

There are different sources (for example: [Seder Olam Rabbah, chapter 5](https://www.sefaria.org/Seder_Olam_Rabbah.5.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), which deals with yetzias mitzrayim and the splitting of the sea) that explain when important events took place in our history. However, I was reading a work by Immanuel Velikovsky, called: ["Ages in Chaos"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ages_in_Chaos#:%7E:text=Ages%20in%20Chaos%20is%20a,five%20centuries%20out%20of%20step.).

On page 124, Velikovsky writes:

> Six hundred years disappeared from the history of the Jewish people, or six hundred years were doubled in the history of Egypt and in the history of many other people as well. If the fault lies in Egyptian history, the only possibility is that events of that history are described twice, and six hundred years is repeated

Let's take this approach. I am wondering if there are any sources that explain the missing of these years. I once heard that the Rambam wrote that our calendar is a bit off. Does this mean that Matan Torah, which is widely accepted to have taken place in the Hebrew year 2448 or 1313 BCE, might have occured years later?

Related reading: ["The Missing 168 Years in Jewish History"](https://outorah.org/p/47650/) (Rabbi Anthony Manning)